# Error executing openssl command from bash but works from command line

Tags: bash, openssl

I deal a lot with SSL certificates, private keys, CSRs, etc. I have a number of small bash scripts that automate my tasks.  One of these scripts generates a new private key and CSR for an SSL certificate, using openssl.  The script is effectively just one line plus error checking - to save me typing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Format: $0 hostname"
    echo "   e.g. $0 www.example.com"
    exit 2
fi

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout "$1.key" -out "$1.csr" \
            -subj "/C=GB/ST=County/L=City/O=My Company Ltd./CN=$1"

cat "$1.csr"
```

This has been working fine.  However recently I need more and more certs with SANs added, so I modified the script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Format: $0 hostname"
        echo "   e.g. $0 www.example.com [SAN1 SAN2 ...]"
        exit 2
fi

SANS=""
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
    SANS=""
    for san in "${@:2}"; do
        SANS="${SANS}DNS:${san}, "
    done
    SANS="-addext \"subjectAltName = ${SANS%,*}\""
fi


openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout "$1.key" -out "$1.csr" \
            -subj "/C=GB/ST=County/L=City/O=My Company Ltd./CN=$1" \
            $SANS

cat "$1.csr"
```

Now the script doesn't work any more, simply producing

```
req: Use -help for summary.
```

I modified the last bit of the script like so:

```
CMD="openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout \"$1.key\" -out \"$1.csr\" \
            -subj \"/C=GB/ST=County/L=City/O=My Company Ltd./CN=$1\" \
            $SANS"
echo $CMD
$CMD
```

This allowed me to see the command before it's executed.  The command is correct and when I copy/paste this command into the bash prompt, I do get the right results.  So what causes this command to fail when executing from the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your `SANS` variable, which is a string.  You use the variable unquoted, which means the shell will split it on whitespace (and apply filename globbing on all the split-up parts).

Instead of storing *multiple separate strings* in one string, use an array:

```bash
SANS=()
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
    subjAltNames=("${@:2}")
    IFS=,
    SANS=(-addext "subjectAltName = ${subjAltNames[*]}")
fi
```

If `$#` is greater than 1, this gives you `SANS` as an array containing the two elements `-addext` and the string `subjectAltNames =`  followed by a comma-delimited list of strings from the command line arguments.  The comma-delimited list is created from another array, `subjAltNames`, and by using it as `${subjAltNames[*]}`, its elements are concatenated with the first character of `$IFS` as the delimiter (this is why we set `IFS` to a comma beforehand).

You would later use `SANS` as `"${SANS[@]}"` to correctly access the list of individually quoted elements:

```bash
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout "$1.key" -out "$1.csr" \
            -subj "/C=GB/ST=County/L=City/O=My Company Ltd./CN=$1" \
            "${SANS[@]}"
```

If the `SANS` array is empty, it will not contribute an empty argument to the end of the list of arguments.

Comment: Perfect, that did it!